# java.util.scanner Explanation

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Dear Secretive Hackers and Legendary Programmers,

I already know that the scanner is used to recognize user input much like the java bufferedreader in the io section of the virtual java handbook. The question is how can you apply the scanner in the simplest terms, meaning beginning with a set button such as {A} or say {1} for instance? How do I apply the scanner to get java to realize these buttons were pressed, and if so, then print the set condition?

Logic:
Scanner application??... (I need help with this)

If A, then `System.out.println("Hi, my name is A!!")`

If 1, then `System.out.println("Hi, my name is 1!!")`

Thanks much

Comment: What do you mean by button? `Scanner` is used for parsing text (such as input from a terminal), not graphical user interfaces.

Comment: I'm actually working in the terminal and not on GUI. What I mean by button is I am trying to figure out a way of using the scanner to get java to realize I pressed a key on my board and then do something in the terminal. In other words after I compile and run nothing happens, but if I pressed a set key to a condition print under the condition.

Answer (score 2):

To the extent of my (somewhat limited) knowledge, a Scanner reading System.in will not pass any data until the enter (return) key is pressed (as until that point, it has no data *to* pass), so it would not respond to lone button presses. It will respond if you do press enter, so use something like:

```java
Scanner yourScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
//Creates a scanner that reads from the terminal.
System.out.println("What is my name? "); 
//Whatever you want the user to be asked, let them know what to input.
String theirResponse = scan.next(); 
//Or .nextLine() if the input contains a space in the middle
System.out.println("Hi, my name is " + theirResponse + "!!");
//Prints out and uses their response.
```

Unfortunately, `Scanner` is not a very good way to go for key listening.

Comment: If you use `next()`, it will use the characters it finds until it finds a space whilst `nextLine()` will use the characters it finds until a return (`\n`). Given `Hello, world!`, `next()` would be "Hello," whilst `nextLine()` would be "Hello, world!"

Comment: Thanks @nrubin29 Edited to clarify

Comment: Good edit, but the part you added about `KeyListener`s is irrelevant as the OP is using the terminal and not a GUI: *"I'm actually working in the terminal and not on GUI."*

Comment: And now all of this is irrelevant because it looks like the OP deleted themself...unless that's your old account...I'm confused...

Comment: @nrubin29 Fixed the GUI thing, and no, not my account... This question isn't irrelevant if any other person has the same question, and I like to keep my answers in good shape. :)

Comment: I agree, I just got confused when I saw this question was asked in January by a deleted(?) user and edited today by you.

Comment: Yeah. I'm just making sure that my few sources of rep are of the best worth. Sorry for bumping it so much.